# Which is faster to link? Many small .so files or few large .so files?

Tags: c++, g++, ld

I have a large c++ project (g++/linux) with a lot of code generation where the build system groups the generated code by directory names at depth=1 into .so files

This causes a few problems when it comes to releasing smaller chunks, so I am trying to make it more granular, i.e. depth=5, which will increase the number of .so files (by 5 fold, 20 to 100) but allow us to make changes and deploy at a more granular level

During a clean build, when everything is built from scratch, does having many small .so files make a difference in linking time?

Comment: Have you tried it? It's probably going to be different from project-to-project. I think this question is a little too broad. Though, if I were to guess, I'd likely imagine it being slower.

Comment: I am trying it now.  The benefits in granular releases outweigh the compilation time increase, but the code already takes over an hour to build fully on a 40 core machine with 64GB RAM

Comment: The criteria for dll granularity should be the machine code sharing between executables. If you are struggling with build times then you should inspect the organization of your code and build timing. This whole story sound like you are just using a poorly written codegen which emits thousands of translation units for no reason.

Comment: I am inspecting the code organization and I will be splitting up at the .so files.  However, I wanted to know if others have any experience in doing something similar

Answer (score 1):

Is this about GNU/Linux? Dynamic linking is currently very slow because the dependency sorting uses an algorithm which is approximately *O*(*n*³) or thereabouts:

- [RFE: Improve performance of dynamic loader for deeply nested DSO dependencies](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17645)

We should really fix this, but it has not yet happened.  (Some people are concerned about changing the sort order when there are cycles in the dependency graph, that's why it is difficult.)  If you have just a few dozen shared objects, you won't see the load time impact, but it could be a problem if you have 100 or more of them.

Regarding your original question about link editor performance: One curious aspect of ELF is that you can link against a dummy DSO which does not contain any symbols, and replace that at run time with a proper DSO, via `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` and an empty DSO copied to all the sonames for which you need dependencies.  This trick could allow you to link most things in parallel, disregarding run-time dependencies.  This is probably not such a great idea for production builds, especially if you use lazy binding, but during development, it might be helpful.  With this change, splitting things into many small DSOs might not be worthwhile (but that really depends on the library sizes you are currently dealing with).

Also keep in mind that partial upgrades of DSOs can be quite painful, and once you users are doing that, you carefully need to manage dependencies and maintain ABI compatibility across your system.  With small DSOs, you will also have to deal more often with moving symbol definitions from one DSO to another, which can run into curious obstacles if you use symbol versions.